# Xamarin Forms Video Chat Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin, video, signalr, live

I am looking a solution for Video Chatting in Xamarin forms backend Azure. Azure currently not supporting WebRTC. So I plan to do Create 2 live streaming channel for the users. Take one end camera for one live streaming channel and same for another end user. Before I am doing this test, I want to know it will work or not and performance wise good or bad?

Or I can go with signalr?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think neither **Azure Media Services**, nor **SignalR** will give you the low latency you need for a live video chat application.

I think that your best bet when running on **Azure**, will be to grab a **Virtual Machine** and install a 3rd party product such as:

- [Kurento](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/)
- [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) (which I think also offer their product as a SaaS)
- Any other product you might find

Hope it helps!